# Automatically running usb when plugged in

Tags: bash, usb

I want to automatically run script when usb is plugged in, and I found one solution, [Default file permissions for FAT32 USB stick on Raspberry Pi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23097285/default-file-permissions-for-fat32-usb-stick-on-raspberry-pi), before I tried making autorun directly on usb but It says I dont have permission to run that.

I would need some help to understand this solution completely:

```
KERNEL=="sd?1", SYMLINK="stick1"
```

what should I use as SYMLINK ?

This part also I dont understand how to use in my case?

```
 umount /dev/david  2>> /home/pi/mylog.txt
```

in general short explanation would be perfect.